# How to prevent my ankles from banging against each other while skipping rope?

Tags: form, jump-rope

I recently bought a jump rope, and while I haven't gotten around to properly exercising with it, I did a few test runs to test the length. Each time I would jump about 30 seconds or so.

I've noticed that when I jump, I eventually bang my ankle bones together (the medial malleolus, to be accurate), which kinda hurts, and definitely indicative of bad form. I've tried to jump in place, without the rope, to see what kind of form I have, and that happens again, even if I try to keep my feet together while jumping. This happens even if I jump short and controlled jumps (but also with the bad-form tuck-your-feet-back-higher-jumps that I definitely plan to work against).

(I should probably also say that I never used a jump rope before; I'm pretty thin, if that matters.)

What can I do to correct my form, and what kind of problem is this indicative of?

Comment: Sorry about the tags, I don't know which one fit.

Comment: I think they're good.

Comment: Are you jumping straight up or are you pushing outward to jump? Have you tried widening your stance? To be honest, I'm having a bit of trouble thinking about why this would happen.

Comment: @C.Lange: Jumping up. I tried widening my stance, but I naturally prefer my legs to be closer together, especially with very low jumps, so my legs just get back together very quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "*so my legs get back together quickly?*" Why are you swinging your legs as you jump? Have you tried jumping with one feet moving forward and the other backward just ever so slightly in an alternating fashion?

Comment: @DKNguyen: It's just the way my legs move. One of them is ever so slightly shorter than the other, so when I pull both up at the same time there tend to be a bit of motion inwards, I suppose (I never really thought about this until now).

Comment: Have you tested for hypermobility? I share this problem.